# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@heroicons/vue/24/outline'

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, heroicons

I get the error message as soon as I add this reference in my vue component:

```
<script setup>
import { ExclamationTriangleIcon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline'
```

I am using tailwindcss 3.1.8.

I have executed this:

```
npm install @headlessui/vue @heroicons/vue
```

I have version 1.0.6 of heroicons installed. Why is the icon not found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like heroicons 1.0.6 is outdated. Had to get version 2.0.* by calling

```
npm install @heroicons/vue@latest
```

Import of icons had to be changed from `'@heroicons/vue/**'` to `'@heroicons/vue/24/*'`

I also had to switch some old icons with new ones, as they may have been renamed or removed. New Icons may be found at https://unpkg.com/browse/@heroicons/vue@2.0.10/24/outline/ (the page https://vue-hero-icons.netlify.app/ does not work as it still contains old ones)

Comment: this solution works for me to using Nuxt 3 and Vue 3, I had to change to @heroicons/vue/24/outline/index.js and to @heroicons/vue/20/solid/index.js

Answer (score 1):

I was using Typescript, so the error was slightly different.

**Cannot find module '@heroicons/vue/24/outline' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)**

In Visual Studio the problem persists with Typescript.  I solved adding types path in tsconfig.json.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "../../node_modules/@heroicons/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
  },
 ...
}
```

It probably is not resolve particular Javascript problem, but it can help anyone to work in Typescript and land in this answer.